# Cut a mesh based on path on svg file

Tags: modeling

Hi and thanks in advance for contrubitions.
I have a cylinder like mesh in blender. I want to create a patterned cut on its surface based on a .svg file.
I will work on it based on this cut so texturing it and setting it as alpha doesn't work for me.

Comment: [Related?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36642/stamp-cut-another-mesh?s=4|31.8735)

Comment: "Related? – batFINGER" No because i need svg to wrap the object first.

Comment: Suggest clarifying questions with more details, images etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here: [Wrap curve around sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere). 1- Bend .svg into cylinder. 2- Add shrinkwrap modifier. 3- Use Boolean to cut it.